# PHP display results in a drop-down list excluding already selected values

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to display results into a drop-down list from a table column only showing the selected position and other available positions that haven't been assigned.

table to pick results from:

```
TITLE     | LINK        | POSITION  |
-------------------------------------
Home      | home.php    |   1       |
-------------------------------------
Contact   | contact.php |   2       |
-------------------------------------
about     | about.php   |   3       |
-------------------------------------
```

All Positions

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Page with dropdown box

```
/* extract data from table*/ 

if(isset($_GET['edit_id']))
{
$id = $_GET['edit_id'];
extract($update->getID('pages','TITLE',$id));
}

/* dropdown with results*/

<label class="control-label" for="basicinput">POSITION</label>
<select name="POSITION" class="span8" id="POSITION" tabindex="1">
<?php 
$view->menu_drop($POSITION)  
?>
</select>
```

Function filtering dropdown box

```
 <?php
 public function menu_drop($value)
{
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT POSITION FROM pages");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$catg=$row["POSITION "];
if( $value == $catg )
{
echo "<option selected = 'selected' value=\"$catg\">$catg</option>"; 
} else
{ 
/* i am lost here. I would like to display the other available positions excluding the positions already assigned pages in the table*/
}
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: Please explain it clearly. Provide an appropriate example, and also show what code you've tried so far.

Comment: I will do this for you for the low, low price of $95/hour but I must request a good-faith payment of $2,000 to be sent to my bank in Nigeria because it will help me infiltrate an exposed tax bracket and I promise to make you a millionaire, good sir. Thank you kindly for your time. Sincerely, the Ambassador.

Comment: I don't think you would do this at the php backend part. You need to do it at the front end. here is an example but you'll need to pass the information into it. http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
public function menu_drop ($value) {
    echo "<option value=\"0\">Remove Position</option>";
    for ($i= 1; $i <=6; $i++) {
        $found = false;
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT POSITION FROM pages");
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $catg=$row["POSITION"];
            if ($catg == $i && $i != $value) {
                $found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$found) {
            if ($value == $i) {
                echo "<option selected = 'selected' value=\"$i\">$i</option>";  
            } else { 
                echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple mechanism is to use a ternary test in order to set a varibale to `selected` or `nothing` each time round the while loop

Also as class methods are supposed to be encapsultated and effect nothing outside themselves. Make the method build a string containing the html rather than echo it form the method, then, theoretically, you could amend its result if you wanted to.

```
<?php
public function menu_drop($value)
{
    $htm = '';

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT POSITION FROM pages");
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $sel = $value == $row['POSITION'] ? "selected='selected'" : '';
        $htm .= "<option $sel value='{$row['POSITION']}'>{$row['POSITION']}</option>"; 
    }
    return $htm;
}
?>
```

Then change your calling process to

```
/* dropdown with results*/

<label class="control-label" for="basicinput">POSITION</label>
<select name="POSITION" class="span8" id="POSITION" tabindex="1">
<?php 
    echo $view->menu_drop($POSITION);
?>
</select>
```